# how to sum of multiple count on different table and different filter

Tags: mysql, sql, count, google-bigquery, sum

i want to get `box_id`, `date` , `hour` and `sum` of multiple `count id` in different table with different `status` in each table but having same `box_id`,

example

```
table 1
(filter by status = finished)


id   box_id              date                status
i     20      2019-01-01 01:00:00.000 UTC    finished
2     21      2019-01-01 02:00:00.000 UTC    finished
3     21      2019-01-01 01:00:00.000 UTC    unfinished


table 2
(filter by status = start)

id   box_id              date                status
i     21      2019-01-01 01:00:00.000 UTC    start
2     22      2019-01-01 02:00:00.000 UTC    end
3     23      2019-01-01 01:00:00.000 UTC    start
4     24      2019-01-01 01:00:00.000 UTC    start


table 3
(filter by status = close)


id   box_id              date                status
i     21      2019-01-01 03:00:00.000 UTC    close
2     22      2019-01-01 02:00:00.000 UTC    end
3     24      2019-01-01 01:00:00.000 UTC    close

result that i want:

box_id      date        hour       count
20         2019-01-01     1          1
21         2019-01-01     1          1
21         2019-01-01     2          1
21         2019-01-01     3          1
23         2019-01-01     1          1
24         2019-01-01     1          2
```

this is my query that works for table 1:
how i get for all in 1 table ?

```
select box_id, 
date(date_update), 
EXTRACT(hour FROM date_update) as hourly, 
count(id)
from table1
where status = "finished"
group by box_id, date(date_update), EXTRACT(hour FROM date_update)
```

format hour = 0 - 23

Comment: *the table structure like that* Replace with CREATE TABLE. *the result must* Show source data (in INSERT INTO form) which must give this result (of course decrease `count` by records count restriction). PS. Your query must give desired result... what's wrong with it?

Comment: i've been edit my questions, every table has unique id, and i want to get sum of multiple count id on 3 tables based on filter that applied in each table like above

Comment: In each table you have box_id and this field is present in all the three tables, right? Furthermore, you want count each box_id for each table an then sum them together in the final result for each box_id, am I correct?

Comment: Yeah right ! sum together with the filter different `status` in each table

Comment: @NFA, each table has the all the same  value for box_id?

Comment: What I mean is if there are box_id present in table2 which are not in table1. Is this possible?

Comment: @AlexandreMoraes is possible, i want to get all unique box_id on 3 tables

Comment: @NFA, I have posted an answer which I believe satisfies your conditions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207099/discussion-between-alexandre-moraes-and-nfa).

Comment: @NFA . . . Without examples of the data in all three tables, the question doesn't have enough information to be answered, in my opinion.

Comment: @GordonLinoff i have been post the example of data

Comment: @AlexandreMoraes i have been edit my questions, hope it more understanding

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `date` field is of TIMESTAMP data type  - below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT box_id, date, hour, COUNT(1) cnt
FROM (
  SELECT box_id, DATE(date) date, EXTRACT(HOUR FROM date) hour 
  FROM `project.dataset.table1` WHERE status = 'finished' UNION ALL
  SELECT box_id, DATE(date) date, EXTRACT(HOUR FROM date) hour 
  FROM `project.dataset.table2` WHERE status = 'start' UNION ALL
  SELECT box_id, DATE(date) date, EXTRACT(HOUR FROM date) hour 
  FROM `project.dataset.table3` WHERE status = 'close'
)
GROUP BY box_id, date, hour
```

You can test, play with above using sample/dummy data from your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table1` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, 20 box_id, TIMESTAMP '2019-01-01 01:00:00.000 UTC'date, 'finished' status UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 21, '2019-01-01 02:00:00.000 UTC', 'finished' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 21, '2019-01-01 01:00:00.000 UTC', 'unfinished' 
), `project.dataset.table2` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, 21 box_id, TIMESTAMP '2019-01-01 01:00:00.000 UTC' date, 'start' status UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 22, '2019-01-01 02:00:00.000 UTC', 'end' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 23, '2019-01-01 01:00:00.000 UTC', 'start' UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 24, '2019-01-01 01:00:00.000 UTC', 'start' 
), `project.dataset.table3` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, 21 box_id, TIMESTAMP '2019-01-01 03:00:00.000 UTC' date, 'close' status UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 22, '2019-01-01 02:00:00.000 UTC', 'end' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 24, '2019-01-01 01:00:00.000 UTC', 'close' 
)
SELECT box_id, date, hour, COUNT(1) cnt
FROM (
  SELECT box_id, DATE(date) date, EXTRACT(HOUR FROM date) hour 
  FROM `project.dataset.table1` WHERE status = 'finished' UNION ALL
  SELECT box_id, DATE(date) date, EXTRACT(HOUR FROM date) hour 
  FROM `project.dataset.table2` WHERE status = 'start' UNION ALL
  SELECT box_id, DATE(date) date, EXTRACT(HOUR FROM date) hour 
  FROM `project.dataset.table3` WHERE status = 'close'
)
GROUP BY box_id, date, hour
-- ORDER BY box_id, date, hour
```

with result

```
Row box_id  date        hour    cnt  
1   20      2019-01-01  1       1    
2   21      2019-01-01  1       1    
3   21      2019-01-01  2       1    
4   21      2019-01-01  3       1    
5   23      2019-01-01  1       1    
6   24      2019-01-01  1       2
```

Below are slightly refactored versions of the same (with same output obviously)

```
#standardSQL
SELECT box_id, DATE(date) date, EXTRACT(HOUR FROM date) hour, 
  COUNTIF(
    (t = 1 AND status = 'finished') OR
    (t = 2 AND status = 'start') OR
    (t = 3 AND status = 'close') 
  ) cnt
FROM (
  SELECT 1 t, * FROM `project.dataset.table1` UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, * FROM `project.dataset.table2` UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, * FROM `project.dataset.table3` 
)
GROUP BY box_id, date, hour
HAVING cnt > 0
```

OR

```
#standardSQL
SELECT box_id, DATE(date) date, EXTRACT(HOUR FROM date) hour, COUNT(1) cnt
FROM (
  SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.table1` WHERE status = 'finished' UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.table2` WHERE status = 'start' UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.table3` WHERE status = 'close'
)
GROUP BY box_id, date, hour
```

Comment: i am try the 1 query, amazing ! its work for me, thanks a ton master !

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments since you want to add fields from multiple tables I recommend you use a [JOIN](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#join-types). There are multiple **JOIN** types, in case all the table have the same amount and values for *box_id*, you can use [INNER JOIN](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#join-types). However, if that is not the case and you still want to see the count for each *box_id*, even though this *box_id* might not be present in all the three tables I suggest you to use [FULL JOIN](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#full-outer-join).

Below I have written a simplified example where I used ***FULL JOIN***, together with other built in functions in BigQuery.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT
      coalesce(t1.box_id, t2.box_id, t3.box_id) AS id,
      (ifnull(t1.count,0)+ifnull(t2.count,0)+ifnull(t3.count,0)) AS count
    FROM (
      SELECT
        box_id,
        count(box_id) AS count
      FROM
        `source_table1`
      WHERE status = 'finished'
      GROUP BY
        box_id) t1
    FULL JOIN (
      SELECT
        box_id,
        count (box_id) AS count
      FROM
        `source_table2`
      WHERE status = 'finished'
      GROUP BY
        box_id ) t2
    ON
      t1.box_id=t2.box_id
    FULL JOIN (
      SELECT
        box_id,
        count (box_id) AS count
      FROM
        `source_table3`
      WHERE status = 'finished'
      GROUP BY
        box_id) AS t3
    ON
      t1.box_id=t3.box_id
    WHERE
      t1.box_id IS NOT NULL
      OR t2.box_id IS NOT NULL
      OR t3.box_id IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY
      id
```

Notice that I used [COALESCE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators) to select the *box_id*, in case this field does not exist in table 1 it will move to table 2 and so on. Subsequently, I have used [IFNULL](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/IFNULL-Function_66194064) to sum the result of the count encountered in each table, this method was used to make sure the count is set to zero when *box_id* is not in the table. Finally, I used the **WHERE** clause, so the count would respect the condition you imposed.

I used the sample data beneath to reproduce your case:

**Table 1:**

[image]

**Table 2 and Table 3:**

[image]

Hence, the output was:

[image]

I hope it helps.

Comment: it works, but i did not get the date (i want to group by box_id and date). how it is ?

Comment: Can you tell me how do you want to select the table, because since you are counting one field I need to know how the data field behaves. Are they all the same for each box_id? Or do you have a rule to select them?